# Reason for loss of reputation

Tags: support, reputation

What can cause a user to suddenly lose a lot of reputation? I had 4415 reputation one day, and the next day I was suddenly at 2585. How is that possible?

Comment: Do you have an example user for this?

Comment: myself http://stackoverflow.com/users/54271/ashutosh-singh

Comment: Check the email associated with your Stack Overflow account.

Comment: I wonder what @bill's mail said (and why his comment has 6 upvotes)?

Comment: I rolled back to @Michael's revision because it contained some corrections (It's normal to do this on SO). If you really want your original version, feel free to roll back again

Answer (score 8):

Well, your reputation graph is *suspicious*

[image]

Are you sure you haven't been upvoting your stuff with another account (that also belongs to you?)

Alternatively, what does [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) report to you?

Comment: @Juan: [My graph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1588?tab=reputation) looks the same, but that's because I've only recently started answering a lot of questions.

Comment: This is a hockey stick graph.  He is blowing up!

Comment: Wow.  Almost every single answer he's given in the last two weeks has received 3-4 upvotes.  Not a single one has 0 or 1 vote.

Comment: At least something fishy has to go on here, otherwise SO wouldn't have kicked in and removed the votes.

Comment: While I agree *something* was obviously happening here, like a puppet account being deleted etc...don't go by *just* the graph.  For example, mine has a similar pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/users/13249?tab=reputation

Comment: @Nick: Okay, what the heck happened last January?  Did you finish school and free up a bunch of time?  New diet?  New Year's resolution?  Discover a bunch of +1 INT potions?  WHAT THE HECK???

Comment: i have been regular on the forum and its not see the answer acceptance ratings that also talk about more things

Comment: @Ashutosh: Please reword your previous comment - at the moment it's not at all clear what you mean.

Comment: I have been a regular contributor on stackoverflow from past month or so and my answer acceptance rating would be around 35-40% that shows my most of the answers are correct. and if for that few users regularly upvote me is it against ethics of stackoverflow. if i have few admirers who upvote me regularly is it against ethics of stackoverflow.

Comment: the person who is commenting on fishy graph this graph is after point deductions not before that

Comment: Yes I know @ash, I was just pointing out that it's suspicious, I'm not accusing you of anything. At the very least, the graph before the deduction would be more steep -- When you say you have "a few admirers", is it possible they work with you and use SO from the same IP?

Comment: do you mean to say that people in same organizations would have same IP? I am sure no body uses my workstation at work and my home no one uses SO except me

Comment: @Ashutosh: Yes, a whole organization might all have the same *public* IP. Your workstations might all have different internal IPs though. A common reason would be if your organization uses NAT (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

Comment: @Bill, a lot of expert answerers became active around the Dec/Jan time frame.  All with hockey-stick rep graphs.  Bit of a watershed moment, that's when the fluff ended at SO afaict.  Thanks btw, probably wasn't easy.

Comment: @Brad - I think you've hit the nail on the head - such a consistent pattern of votes especially in a tag like sharepoint where upvotes are given very sparingly. Oh, but thats down to "admirers" of course...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the moderators seized upon (they have hidden data like IP addresses, upvote/downvote by users etc) but these stats show clearly the effect of your Admirers.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/730/find-sock-puppets-look-for-suspicious-upvote-patterns-in-a-particular-tag?tagname=sharepoint

Users like Rex and Michael Stum, Bjørn Furuknap, Lars Fastrup etc etc,  get high avg scores but look at the variation (StdDev) - some get loads of upvotes, some not so much.

Your scores Standard Deviation is tiny in comparison - i.e. each and every answer gets a very consistent number of upvotes.

Totally against the usual stack overflow voting pattern.